# Why does my FirstFactorial program keep looping back to while condition even after the condition is not met

Tags: c, function, recursion, while-loop, factorial

Here's the code snippet, this when run with number `4` outputs `2424242448484848288288288288576576576576`. Not sure as to why would the execution would jump back to while loop after exiting the function code. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int result = 1;
void FirstFactorial(int);

void FirstFactorial(int num) {
    // code goes here
    while (num > 0) {
        result = result * num;
        num--;
        FirstFactorial(num);
    }
    printf("%d", result);
}

int main(void) {
    int var;
    // keep this function call here
    printf ("Enter your no.\n");
    scanf("%d", &var);
    FirstFactorial(var);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because it is a different (local) `num` in the called function. The caller's num has still only decremented once when the recursive call returns. And, as the recursion drops back down, even function exit prints a value (with no separator).

Comment: Note, an `int`'s maximum value is most likely 2,147,483,647.  This allows a factorial of, at most, `12!`.

Comment: @WeatherVane When you say different num, I don't understand. Can you please explain?

Comment: @FiddlingBits Yes, I am just trying out a 4! but still prints out some weird things

Comment: Each instance of `FirstFactorial` has it's own copy of `num`.  They are totally independent of each other.

Comment: A *copy* of `num` is passed to the next function recursion. When it decrements, the caller's value is not touched.

Comment: It will be clearer if you print a space or a newline after every message.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you mean to use recursion or can you just use a loop?

Comment: I don't know if you have grasped recursion, but *suppose* each time it calls itself it is given a suffix, like `FirstFactorial_1(int num_1)` and then `FirstFactorial_2(int num_2)` etc. and each is independent of the previous one. When each one ends, it passes control back to the previous one - it doesn't just stop. And each one prints a message on the way out, and these messages are all run into each other because there is no newline.

Comment: @WeatherVane,  Thanks for the explanation

Comment: @FiddlingBits Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the function

```
void
FirstFactorial(int num)
{
  // code goes here
  while(num > 0)
    {
      result = result * num;
      num--;
      FirstFactorial(num);
    }
  printf("%d", result);
}
```

each its iteration calls itself `num` times and all iterations together output the global variable result.

So for example in the first call of the function the function calls itself in the while loop for the range of values [num, 1].

Remove the while loop and do not use the global variable.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long int factorial( unsigned long long int n )
{
    return n < 2 ? 1 : n * factorial( n - 1 );
}

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "%llu! = %llu\n", 4llu, factorial( 4 ) );
    printf( "%llu! = %llu\n", 20llu, factorial( 20 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
4! = 24
20! = 2432902008176640000
```

Pay attention that the maximum value you may specify is 20.

Comment: never hire a developer who computes the factorial using recursion :-)

Answer (score 0):

Either you implement the factorial with a loop or you do it recursively.

Both ways are feasible but your code mixes it up.

Answer (score 0):

Your function mixes iterative and recursive approaches. You can correct it by removing the useless recursion which causes multiple intermediary results to be computed and printed. Defining `result` as a global variable is also a mistake, especially since you do not reinitialize it before the loop. Using type `long long` will allow for larger factorials to be computed. Adding a trailing `\n` after the `printf` conversion specifier is advisable too.

Here is a corrected version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void FirstFactorial(int num) {
    long long result = 1;

    while (num > 1) {
        result = result * num;
        num--;
    }
    printf("%lld\n", result);
}

int main(void) {
    int var;
    // keep this function call here
    printf("Enter your number\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &var) == 1)
        FirstFactorial(var);
    return 0;
}
```